# Initializing Deliveryfile failing

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

I am using fastlane and tried to initialize Delivery by running:

```
fastlane delivery init
```

and I get this:

> admin@macbook fastlane-integration-ios % fastlane deliver init [⠸] 
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday_middleware-0.13.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:14:
>   warning: Capturing the given block using Proc.new is deprecated; use
>   `&block` instead [✔]   [14:40:46]: Login to App Store Connect
>   (xxx@xxx.com)
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday_middleware-0.13.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:14:
>   warning: Capturing the given block using Proc.new is deprecated; use
>   `&block` instead
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/faraday_middleware-0.13.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:14:
>   warning: Capturing the given block using Proc.new is deprecated; use
>   `&block` instead [14:40:48]: Login successful
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:624:
>   warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
>   [14:40:48]: The Bundle Identifier of your App:
>   xxx.com.fastlane-integration
>
> +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+ |                         deliver 2.142.0 Summary
>   |
>   +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+ | run_precheck_before_submit           | false
>   | | app_identifier                       |
>   xxx.com.fastlane-integration | | screenshots_path
>   | ./fastlane/screenshots           | | metadata_path
>   | ./fastlane/metadata              | | username
>   | xxx@xxx.com               | | platform                             |
>   ios                              | | edit_live
>   | false                            | | use_live_version
>   | false                            | | skip_binary_upload
>   | false                            | | skip_screenshots
>   | false                            | | skip_metadata
>   | false                            | | skip_app_version_update
>   | false                            | | force
>   | false                            | | overwrite_screenshots
>   | false                            | | submit_for_review
>   | false                            | | reject_if_possible
>   | false                            | | automatic_release
>   | false                            | | phased_release
>   | false                            | | reset_ratings
>   | false                            | | precheck_default_rule_level
>   | warn                             | | individual_metadata_items
>   | []                               | |
>   ignore_language_directory_validation | false
>   | | precheck_include_in_app_purchases    | true
>   |
>   +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
>
> Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
>
> ➡️  can't modify frozen String: "true" for enterprise builds
>       https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16055 [open] 9 
>       3 hours ago
>
> ➡️  can't modify frozen String
>       https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15415 [closed] 3 
>       30 Nov 2019
>
> ➡️  "DEPRECATION WARNING: Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed is
>   deprecated! Use Faraday::ConnectionFailed instead." / Fastlane
>   spaceauth: Could not login to App Store Connect
>       https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15397 [closed] 18 
>       3 days ago
>
> and 5 more at:
>   https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=can%27t%20modify%20frozen%20String%3A%20%22%22&type=Issues&utf8=✓
>
> You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your
>   browser. Traceback (most recent call last):   18: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'    17:
>   from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:23:in`load'     16:
>   from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/bin/fastlane:23:in
>   `<top (required)>'    15: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:111:in`
>   take_off'    14: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/commands_generator.rb:17:in
>   `start'   13: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/commands_generator.rb:182:in`
>   run'     12: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in
>   `run!'    11: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in`
>   run!'    10: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in
>   `run_active_command'   9: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in`
>   run'      8: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in
>   `call'     7: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/commands_generator.rb:116:in`
>   block (2 levels) in run'      6: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:21:in
>   `run'      5: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:45:in`
>   generate_deliver_file'    4: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:63:in
>   `generate_metadata_files'      3: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:63:in`
>   each'     2: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:64:in
>   `block in generate_metadata_files'     1: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:64:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:70:in
>   `block (2 levels) in generate_metadata_files': can't modify frozen
>   String: "" (FrozenError)  18: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:23:in`'    17:
>   from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'     16:
>   from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/bin/fastlane:23:in`
>   '    15: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:111:in
>   `take_off'    14: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/commands_generator.rb:17:in`
>   start'   13: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/commands_generator.rb:182:in
>   `run'     12: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in`
>   run!'    11: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in
>   `run!'    10: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in`
>   run_active_command'   9: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in
>   `run'      8: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in`
>   call'     7: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/commands_generator.rb:116:in
>   `block (2 levels) in run'      6: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:21:in`
>   run'      5: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:45:in
>   `generate_deliver_file'    4: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:63:in`
>   generate_metadata_files'      3: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:63:in
>   `each'     2: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:64:in`
>   block in generate_metadata_files'     1: from
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:64:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.142.0/deliver/lib/deliver/setup.rb:70:in`
>   block (2 levels) in generate_metadata_files': \e[31m[!] can't modify
>   frozen String: ""\e[0m (FrozenError) admin@macbook
>   fastlane-integration-ios %

Why this error is happening?

Comment: Could you please open an issue over at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/new?template=BUG_REPORT.md Add the required information and it's easier to help you.

Comment: @Max I downgraded to Ruby version 2.6.5 and it worked. With 2.7.0 I was getting this error... I am still not sure why this happening so I will open issue on github soon as I find time today.